# In what extent replace the same image url affect the performance in different browser?

Tags: html, image, performance, browser, cross-browser

In the following browser:
IE8+, firefox, chrome

The case is : there is a menu bar, I would like to add the image to the icon only when it is show:

e.g.

```
if ($('#menu').css('display') != 'none') {
   $('#icon1').attr('background-image','url("a.jpg")');
}
```

Compare with

```
if ($('#menu').css('display') != 'none') {
   if ($('#icon1').attr('background-image') == '') {
        $('#icon1').attr('background-image','url("a.jpg")');
   }
}
```

Both of them have the same effect , however, which one are more effective? I doubt that modern browser such as Chrome would be better for using case 1, is it true? Thanks

Comment: the menu bar can be toogle on/off so the background url change each time when the user toogle on the menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use `:visible` selector instead of checking the value of display propery.

```
if ($('#menu').is(':visible')) {
   $('#icon1').attr('background-image','url("a.jpg")');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to set the background image using CSS.
Here you just hide and show the menu. No need to do it via javascript (jQuery).

When you show the menu, it will load the image and then show it on the page.

For better way, you need to preload the image or do it via CSS.